# Can't use replay memory with policy gradient, why?

Tags: policy-gradient, actor-critic

> One of the approaches to improving the stability of the Policy
>   Gradient family of methods is to use multiple environments in
>   parallel. The reason behind this is the fundamental problem we
>   discussed in Chapter 6, Deep Q-Network, when we talked about the
>   correlation between samples, which breaks the independent and
>   identically distributed (i.i.d) assumption, which is critical for
>   Stochastic Gradient Descent (SDG) optimization. The negative
>   consequence of such correlation is very high variance in gradients,
>   which means that our training batch contains very similar examples,
>   all of them pushing our network in the same direction. However, this
>   may be totally the wrong direction in the global sense, as all those
>   examples could be from one single lucky or unlucky episode. With our
>   Deep Q-Network (DQN), we solved the issue by storing a large amount of
>   previous states in the replay buffer and sampling our training batch
>   from this buffer. If the buffer is large enough, the random sample
>   from it is much better representation of the states distribution at
>   large. Unfortunately, this solution won't work for PG methods, at most
>   of them are on-policy, which means that we have to train on samples
>   generated by our current policy, so, remembering old transitions is
>   not possible anymore.

The above excerpt is from Maxim Lapan in the book *Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-on* page 284.

How being on-policy preventing us from using the replay buffer with the PG? Can you explain to me mathematically why we can't use replay buffer with A3C for instance?